# http socket proxy server

Tags: vb.net, http, sockets, proxy

i think you should make it like

```
Browser                            Proxy                     HTTP server
send tcp request (header) >---------|
                                   \|/
                                   read header
                                   redirect header >---------|
                                                            \|/
                                                            do stuff
                                                            make header
 Get Header <--------------------< redirect header <------< send header
                                                            read content
                                                            morph content (like .php )
 Get content <-------------------< redirect content <-----< send content
```

i tried to make it like this but it didn't work out
it was buggy and it only worked for one server

i did it trying to open the program on other computers but to only accepted local host

is this te correct way or do i need to change my view on this?

Comment: your question is not clear enough